# Do we need a community wiki / canonical "hire a professional" Question and Answer?

Tags: discussion, scope, community-wiki, canonical

Certain questions fall outside our site guidelines because they might involve tracking living or very-recently-deceased individuals.

Should we write a community wiki / canonical answer about how to hire professional genealogists for this task, which we can then point people to as we close their question?

Answer (score 6):

No, because tracking living or very-recently-deceased individuals often does not require one to hire a professional genealogist.

I was under the impression that the no-mention-of-living-people was to protect the privacy of living people. We should not give the false impression that one must hire a professional genealogist to trace a living person.